# Redirigir al home cierre sesión usuario

Tags: php, wordpress

El código que se describe a continuación permite que cuando un usuario esté logueado cambie el menú, localizado en el header, de "Login/registro" a "Cerrar sesión" y a la inversa. La cuestión es que cuando cierra sesión el usuario, el enlace me dirige a la página de login que tiene Wordpress por defecto. **¿Cómo modificaría el siguiente código para que al cerrar sesión me lleve al home de la web?**

He visto algunas soluciones por Google, pero no se cómo las puedo incrustar en este código.

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in()) {

            echo $items = '<li class="right"><a href="'. 
wp_login_url(get_permalink()) .'">'. __("Log Out") .'</a></li>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<div class="login-nav">';
            $login_menu_args = array(
            'theme_location'  => 'login',
            'container'       => 'ul',
            'menu_class'      => 'nolmp',
            'echo'            => true,
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            );
            wp_nav_menu( $login_menu_args );
            echo '</div>';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando `wp_login_url(get_permalink())` por `p_logout_url( home_url() )`, en la documentación oficial de **wordpress** por defecto es:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
```

y lo que tu quieres seria:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: He introducido esta sugerencia, pero se muestra una pantalla de error cuando se cierra la sesión con el siguiente mensaje. ¿pudiera ser por que estoy trabajando en localhost(XAMPP)?:"¡Acceso prohibido!Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto solicitado. El objeto está protegido contra lectura o el servidor no puede leerlo.Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.Error 403 localhost Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/5.6.37"

Comment: @fernanf, creo que puede ser mala configuración en la permisología, todas las carpetas de un sitio WordPress deben tener un permiso de de 744 o 755, todos los archivos de WordPress deben tener un permiso de archivo de 644 o 640, para más tips fijate en este post https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/